# php codeigniter mysql joins

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, join

Ok so im working on my first ever php/mysql project having come from a software position.  I am learning codeigniter and i have worked out that this mysql join will get me friends statuses based on an user.id, how do i add in all my posts to that do i have to do an AND query?

```
select * from friendships
join users on users.`id` = friendships.`friend_id`
join statuses on statuses.`user_id` = users.id
where friendships.`user_id` = 2 
ORDER BY statuses.`id` desc
```

Any help greatly appreciated

Comment: is this query not working? you're not getting the results you want ?

Comment: im getting all my friends statuses which is great, but i would like to see mine in the array too

Comment: this part: where friendships.`user_id` = 2  will make sure that you get information only for person with user_id = 2. If you want to get information for all the users then you need to remove that where clause.

Comment: yes, im trying to get the users that follow me (eg my id=2), join with their statuses but i want to join my statuses too so i can build a combined array

Answer (score 1):

Join query in codeigniter can be written as:

```
$this->db->select("*");
$this->db->from("friendships");
$this->db->join("users","users.id = friendships.friend_id");
$this->db->join("statuses","statuses.user_id = users.id");
$this->db->where("friendships.user_id",2);
$this->db->order_by("statuses.id","desc");
$result=$this->db->get();
```

or

```
$this->db->select("*");
$this->db->join("users","users.id = friendships.friend_id");
$this->db->join("statuses","statuses.user_id = users.id");
$this->db->where("friendships.user_id",2);
$this->db->order_by("statuses.id","desc");
$result=$this->db->get("friendships");
```

Comment: Yes thats what I have above, but how do i add in my own statuses to that? what you have there only returns my friends statuses

Comment: This is select query not insert or update query. if you have to apply condition on  statuses table column then user $this->db->where("statuses.columnname","value");

Answer (score 0):

Well, CodeIgniter abstracts DB interaction through ActiveRecord (so writing full SQL query strings really isn't necessary). They do a better job of explaining it than I could:

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html

Comment: I know, i plan to convert it to the active record style after, i just want to get the hang of mysql first

Comment: Do both at the same time. Use active record to create the query you need it is easy. Then you can also echo the query that active record has built for you.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just add each user as a follower of themselves in your friendships table?  So on registration you add them to users table and to the friendships table.

User 1 follows User 1 etc

Answer (score 0):

### You can also  use this query in codeigniter

```
$query = $this->db->query("select * from friendships
                           join users on users.`id` = friendships.`friend_id`
                           join statuses on statuses.`user_id` = users.id
                           where friendships.`user_id` = 2 
                           ORDER BY statuses.`id` desc");
$result = $query->row_array();
```